# What are the sets of integers obtained from multiplication/division from a given set of primes called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

We are given some (finite) set of primes $P=\{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$. Define the following two sets:

1. $S$ is the set of all integers that can be generated from $P$ by multiplying members of any subset of $P$, possibly by repeating some of them. That is: 
   $$S=\{z|z=\prod^{n}_{i=1}p_i^{x_i}\wedge {x_i}\mbox{ is a non-negative integer}\}$$
2. $T$ is the set of all rational numbers that can be generated from $P$ by multiplying and dividing members of any subset of $P$, possibly by repeating some of them. That is: 
   $$T=\{z|z=\prod^{n}_{i=1}p_i^{x_i}\wedge {x_i}\mbox{ is an integer}\}$$

Is there any name given to $S$ and $T$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S$ is the submonoid of $(\mathbb Z^*, \cdot)$ generated by $P$.

$T$ is the subgroup of $(\mathbb Q^*, \cdot)$ generated by $P$.

Comment: Don't they both require an identity element?

Comment: in your definition they both contain 1....

Comment: oh yes, my mistake. :)

Answer (score 3):

A set with a binary operation (like multiplication) which is associative (parentheses can be dropped between multiplications) and closed under multiplication is generally called a *semigroup*. If it also contains an identity element (here it is $1$), then the semigroup is a *monoid*. If, furthermore, every element has an inverse (the inverse of $a$ is $\frac{1}{a}$), then the monoid becomes a *group*.

In particular, $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual multiplication is a monoid, and $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual multiplication is a group.

The key word here is "generated."

If $M$ is a monoid, the set $B$ is *generated* by a subset $A\subseteq M$ if the elements in $B$ are precisely the products of those elements in $A$ (including the empty product, which is taken to be the identity). It's not difficult to show that $B$ is itself a monoid, and so is called a submonoid of $M$.

Similarly, f $G$ is a group, the set $B$ is *generated* by a subset $A\subseteq G$ if the elements in $B$ are precisely the products  of those elements in $A$ **and their inverses** (including the empty product). As before, $B$ is a group and so a *subgroup* of $G$.

Thus, we apply these definitions to give us the names:

$S$ is "the submonoid (of $\mathbb{Z}$) generated by $P$".

$T$ is "the subgroup (of $\mathbb{Q}$) generated by $P$."

As far as I have seen, we don't have better names for these.